# Navigation drawer layout with navigation bottom bar

Tags: java, android, xml

Can I connect navigation drawer layout with navigation bottom bar in one activity? And how?

Comment: your question is rather vague. could you explain what exactly you want to do

Comment: Can I combine navigation drawer layout with navigation bottom bar in one activity?

Comment: If you're asking from programming perspective yes it is possible and if you're asking from ux perspective, it is also possible as you can see it in Google Plus application